# VBA Excel formatting really really slow

Tags: excel, vba, format, cell

I'm trying to figure out a better way to format cells using VBA. I'm trying to replace an Option button from Excel Forms Control (it works fine but is quite ugly. It looks like old W95). I'm not using activeX as I can't rely that every single user would be able to open this workbook if I use activex. 
So, I was trying to use some VBA to format a cell like a pressed button. It was supposed to be easy with a SUB to format as a pressed and another to unpressed. But this code is running for not less than 13 seconds! It's not feasible.

I've made some research and found other topics, inclusing "VBA Code optimization"
[VBA code optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935462/vba-code-optimization/24936878#24936878)

Other topics:
[slow cell formatting using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987796/slow-cell-formatting-using-vba) But my case is just borders and cell color
[Extremely slow VBA code when formatting cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108564/extremely-slow-vba-code-when-formatting-cells) From where I've got the optimatizaion code

Here is the code

```
Sub BtnSelect()

Dim t

t = Timer

With Selection
            .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = -1740185
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = -1740185
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = -736322
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = -736322
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 16576494
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        
        End With
        
        Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? It's kinda stupid this simple operation takes so long. Thank you very much!

Comment: How can we possibly help without seeing the code?

Comment: Sorry! My bad...

Comment: I just tested it on the full sheet of cells and it took. 1.8 seconds.  Not sure why you are getting 13 seconds.

Comment: You can just use `With .Borders()` and that will cover left/right/top/bottom borders

Comment: ...oops I see you're using different setting per border, so that wouldn't work...

Comment: How does this get called, and what is selected when you call it?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll use a Worksheet_SelectionChange to format a specific cell as a pressed button instead an Option box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs in <0.02 sec for me

```vb
Sub BtnSelect()

    Dim t

    t = Timer

    With Selection
        
        With .Borders()
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = -1740185
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = -1740185
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = -736322
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = -736322
        
        .Interior.Color = 16576494
             
    End With
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```